# File "<string>", line unknown ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

After running this, i get the errors below and i have tried everything else mentioned here and i cannot get past this error

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from os import path, listdir

path__ = "blogs/"
files = [path.join(path__, f) for f in listdir(path__) 

if f.endswith('.xml')]
for file in files:
    print(file)
    parse = ET.XMLParser(encoding="unicode_escape")
    tree = ET.fromstring(file, parser=parse)
```

```
blogs/1000331.female.37.indUnk.Leo.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3427, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-3-40e3bf76804f>", line 8, in <module>
    tree = ET.fromstring(file, parser=parse)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1347, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fromstring`, as the name says takes in a *string* that *is* XML, not a file name. Hence it tries to parse the text

```
blogs/foo.xml
```

as an XML document. You want to use `ET.parse` instead:

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="unicode_escape")
for file in files:
    print(file)
    tree = ET.parse(file, parser=parser)
```

Comment: i tried parsing each single file from my folder but still .. i get the <string> not found 
non-formed error.

Comment: the folder contains at least 19320 xml files. I need to parse each one of them